# Are char a[] = {'a', '\0'} and char *b = "a" equal?

Tags: c

Are `char a[] = {'a', '\0'}` and `char *b = "a"` equal?

what is the difference?

Comment: Which book, tutorial, documentation on type definitions in C did you read?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No they are not equal.

The first create an array of two elements. You can modify the contents of the array as you will (it's mutable).

The second creates a pointer and make it point to the first element of an array containing two elements. The contents of the array that `b` is currently pointing to is *not* mutable, you can not change the contents of that array. Literal strings in C are, in essence, read-only. You can however change the pointer `b` itself, to make it point somewhere else. If you make it point to something which is not a literal string and is not marked `const`, like for example `a`, then the contents can be modified.

---

In memory it would be something like this

For `a`:

```
+-----+------+
| 'a' | '\0' |
+-----+------+
```

The array is a single entity.

And for `b`:

```
+---+     +-----+------+
| b | --> | 'a' | '\0' |
+---+     +-----+------+
```

Here you have two entities, the variable `b` and the array it points to.

Comment: First mutable, second can't change (UB otherwise).

Comment: "*is not mutable*" to avoid (upcoming)  confusion you might like to point out that the "immutability" does not due to the pointer `b` or its type `char*` but to what the pointer actually points to in this specific example. The same pointer variable may very well point to mutable data.